# Comparison of the numbers of particles surviving forever

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, brownian-motion

Consider two $N\text{-}$particle systems as follows : for $1\le i\le N$,

$$X^i_t=1+\int_0^t(b+\phi^i_s) \, ds+W^i_t \quad\mbox{and} \quad Y^i_t=1+ct+W^i_t,\quad \forall t\ge 0,$$

where $c>b>0$ are constants, and $\Phi^N:=(\phi^1_t,\ldots, \phi^N_t)_{t\ge 0}$ is progressively measurable (w.r.t. the Brownian filtration) s.t.

$$\sum_{j=1}^N\phi^i_t \le 1 \quad \mbox{and}\quad \phi^i_t\ge 0,\quad \forall t\ge 0.\tag{$\ast$}$$

Set $R_N:=\#\{1\le i\le N: X^i_t>0 \mbox{ for all } t\ge 0\}$ and $S_N:=\#\{1\le i\le N: Y^i_t>0 \mbox{ for all } t\ge 0\}$, where $\#$ denotes the dimension of finite set. Can we prove that, for any sequence $(\Phi^N)_{N\ge 1}$ satisfying $(\ast)$, one has

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\mathbb E[R_N]}{N}\le \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\mathbb E[S_N]}{N}?$$

A straightforward computation yields

$$\frac{\mathbb E[S_N]}{N}=\mathbb P[Y^1_t>0 \mbox{ for all } t\ge 0] = 1-e^{-2c}.$$